# Decrypt SSL at the TCP level

Tags: networking, ssl, tcp

I'm trying to decrypt SSL at the TCP level for data that I'm sending to a remote server. The reason I'm doing this is because the remote host intermittently sends me RSTs, and I'm trying to identify a pattern. I'd like to see the contents of the last few segments before the RST happens.

I've tried mitmproxy, sslsplit, fiddler, etc. and while I am able to decrypt data at the HTTP level with these tools, what I'd really like is to see a decryption of the data in each TCP segment.

Basically, I'd like to see the equivalent of tcpdump -X, except with the data decrypted. Is there any tool/method to do this?

Comment: This really isn't supposed to be possible. the encryption occurs at the application layer, so anything you capture at the transport layer should be indecipherable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only is @FrankThomas right, but it would be useless even if you managed to do it: RSTs are like doors slammed in your face. They may occur because the server has not loaded a necessary module, because the socket is closed, because the server is behind a (Chinese, but not only) firewall, because there is some gross error (like machines with the same IP, LAN or WAN) in the implementation of the network. All of this is totally unrelated to SSL.

Your best best is to diagnose this issue from within the server, if you are allowed.

Comment: Thanks MariusMatutiae and FrankThomas.
Any suggestions on diagnosing the RSTs given that I have no access to the remote and the RSTs are intermittent?

Comment: @DaveStibrany What kind of connection to the server do you have?

Comment: I'm webscraping them :)

Comment: @DaveStibrany  Doesn't make it easy; but at least it makes sense.

Comment: Do you think the RSTs are in response to the fact that I'm scraping them?

Comment: @DaveStibrany Absolutely yes, it sounds like a firewall related issue.

Comment: Only thing is the RSTs are not consistent. I auto-retry on RSTs and sometimes the particular request will work fine the first time, other times it will RST the first 5 times then work the 6th...

Comment: @DaveStibrany I see, but do you get these RSTs when you connect regularly to their Web page?

Comment: The browser occasionally gets RSTs, but rarely. When scraping, it's the opposite.

Comment: Note that RST's may result from ratelimiting rules, so it may appear intermittent and without rhyme/reason to you, the server may disagree.

Comment: Think I figured it out. Their URL resolves to multiple IP addresses. If I don't stick to the same IP during a session I get the RSTs.

Comment: @DaveStibrany Good going. Like I said, nothing for which decrypting SSL would have been useful.